# Android Instrumentation with a common file

Tags: android, android-instrumentation

I am new to Instrumentation in android. So please help me to achieve this - I have an android apk with classes and methods in it. I need to monitor the time execution of all methods and classes in it using a kind of script file or some file(I mean to say for any apk this script/common file should hold good with some editing of the file like changing methods and classes name instead of editing it in every apk). Is there a way I could achieve this. Any kind of support would help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did this using AspectJ for Android and it is working :)